# PHP and MySQL - Should I validate/sanitize my data when pulling it from my database before displaying to user?

Tags: php, database, validation, security, sanitization

I validate and sanitize all my data before inserting it into the database. Would it be considered a good or a redundant pactice to validate it when pulling it form the database before displaying it?

This boils down to how much to trust your own code. On one extreme, I could forgo the validation completely if I knew that onlyI would use the client-side interface and would *never* make a mistake. On the other, I could validate data in every class in case I'm working with others and they forgot to properly do their job. But what's a generally good practice in this particular case?

Comment: you should  use htmlentities on it after pulling it from the DB before placing it in a page, before that you should validate it on input for certain things.  It's never a bad idea to escape for HTML.  You don't want to do that before saving it as you are then modifying the data beyond what a user gave you.  This makes editing it by the user much more difficult.  Sanitation before should be a yes/no thing not a maybe if I change this it's ok thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input validation should be a yes/no proposition.  You should not modify input and save it.

You should use Htmlentities after pulling from the DB and before showing.  This is because it's better to clean data just before using it at the point of failure.  This is why prepared statements work so well, because there is no external code you rely on.

Say you forget to sanitize 1 field in 1 form, then when you ouput that data to other users you have no way to see that mistake from the code that does the output (assuming its not in the same file).

The less code between the sanitizing and the end result is better.

Now that is not to say save everything and validate it later.  Take an email for example, you should validate that for the proper format before saving.

But for other things you don't want to modify user input.  Take a file upload.  Some people will change the filename to sanitize it, replace spaces etc.  This is good but I prefer to create my own filename, and then show them the origainal file name, while the one I use on the server is a hash of their username and the name of the file.  They never know this, and I get clean filenames.

You start modifying user data, and it becomes a chore to maintain it.  You may have to un-modify it so they can make edits to it... etc.  Which means you are then doing way more work then if you just clean it when outputting it.

Take for example the simple act of replacing a users `\n` line returns with a `<br>` tag.  User inputs into a text field then you change it to html and save it.  (besides security reasons not to do this) when user wants to edit the data, you would have to take the `<br>` and replace them with `\n` so they can edit it.  Security reasons being now you have decided that raw HTML in that field is ok and will just output the raw field, allowing someone a possibility to add their own HTML.  So by modifying user data we have created more work for yourself, and we have made assumptions that the data is clean before inserting it when we output it.  And we cannot see how it was cleaned when we output it.

So the answer is it depends on the data and what sanitation you are doing.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hm, so what you are saying is that I shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` before I insert into the database? I agree with not modifying user data, but would that be secure, even when using PDO prepared statements?

Comment: Yes, the DB doesn't care if there is HTML in it, you just don't want to show that to other users as it could execute javascript on their browser.  If you change it, then you may have to change it back so they can edit it.

Comment: I would say you have to understand the why of cleaning it a bit better.  Prepared statements take care of SQLInjection attacks, and htmlentities (and specialchars) take care of XSS, cross site scripting attacks. Injection sneaks SQL commands into your Query, and XSS uses Javascript to steal cookies (generally)

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually. This also helps with the problem of field length limits because htmlspecialchars expands 1 char into several, incidentially. You've helped me, I'll mark this as solved. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I had to learn not to modify user data the hard way, after spending many hours un-modifing it and what not... lol ... now I am a lazier but smarter programmer.  So I do things the simple way.

Comment: Confidently I like using HTML template systems that automatically apply the escaping to output tags, makes life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is not need of validating or sanitizing the data from the db as you are doing it before inserting 
A attacker always plays with the data which he is sending to the server and just analyis the data coming as a response . They plays with input not with the output.So just secure your data before sending it to server or db .